# Intellij scope and maven scope

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project with 2 sub modules.  Tests within the modules use System.getProperty("user.dir") to load some json fixtures.  When I run the tests from maven, System.getProperty("user.dir") returns the path of the sub modules.  But when I run the tests individually from Intellij by right-click on the file + debug, System.getProperty("user.dir") returns the path of the parent module.  This is a problem because my tests need to have a consistent way to load the fixtures.  Does anyone know how to make System.getProperty("user.dir") return paths to sub modules even when we run it individually in Intellij?

Comment: You should add those test fixture files to 'src/test/resources' instead. Then use 'Class.getResourceAsStream' to get the resource. That will work from both IntelliJ and maven. 'user.dir' is the current working directory (cwd) and is a bad practice to use for this kind of data.

Comment: Ok.  What about shared resources?  For example, if different tests from 2 different modules want to share the same fixture, is there a way to use Class.getResourceAsStream?  The test class cannot be shared in other modules.

Comment: I would suggest you to put that text fixture in a separate module and create a [`test-jar`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) that the other modules can depend on. By doing this you are sharing the fixture among the other modules. Test data will be version controlled and available wherever you use Maven. It must be a nightmare to version control the test data when using `user.dir`.

Comment: I consider this a bug in Intellij, go and vote for it here! http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96122

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the working directory for the test.

To do this edit click the test dropdown menu and select "edit configurations" and change the working directory to the sub-module folder for each test.